# Loading State for CRUD in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to make my first Vue.js CRUD application with Vuex, and I am running into a struggle with how to properly load state.

I have a route that lists all accounts `/accounts` and I am easily loading accounts state for all accounts in a list form.

My challenge/question, how can I effectively use state to view/update an individual record in another route? (ie. `/accounts/1`). If the user refreshes the browser on `/accounts/1` I have no state. What is the best strategy to manage state for both a collection of things, and an individual record in that collection?

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand your problem. Are you using VueX to manage your state?

Comment: Yes, I am using vuex, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on https://github.com/JiriChara/vuex-crud. It creates Restful Vuex modules with all actions: CRETE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE. The source code is pretty straightforward, so you can have a look how state is designed and modified.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain state after a hard reload you might want to make sure state is saved in localstorage then make sure you are using getters to load the data appropriately via lifecycle hooks. Try vue-localstorage

Comment: The title and description of my question are for CRUD, so saving state in localstorage isn't ideal. I need fresh data from an API (database) in order to update records that exist.